# Experimenting with BNF

Tags: lua, compiler-construction

I am trying to experiment with BNF notation. I see complete syntax of Lua5.3 at https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9 . I want to replace `do` and `then` with `{` and `end` with `}` :

```
stat ::=  ‘;’ | 
         varlist ‘=’ explist | 
         functioncall | 
         label | 
         break | 
         goto Name | 
         do block end |                                                  -> { block } 
         while exp do block end |                                        -> while exp { block }
         repeat block until exp |  
         if exp then block {elseif exp then block} [else block] end |    -> if exp { block .... } 
         for Name ‘=’ exp ‘,’ exp [‘,’ exp] do block end |               -> for ........  { block }  
         for namelist in explist do block end |                          -> for ........  { block }
         function funcname funcbody | 
         local function Name funcbody | 
         local namelist [‘=’ explist] 

funcbody ::= ‘(’ [parlist] ‘)’ block end                                  ->  ...........  { block }
```

How do I proceed with above modified syntax to create an interpreter? Can this work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do exactly? Do you want to write an interpreter for a language that's exactly like lua, but with braces instead of keywords for blocks? From scratch or by forking the existing lua interpreter?

Comment: I want to learn the steps of writing a language and making an interpreter for it. I thought first step is to have BNF code (which presently I am taking a modified form of Lua BNF). What are subsequent steps?

Comment: If you want to try this, just edit `llex.c`. It's not very hard.

Comment: As https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/llex.c.html ?

Comment: Yes. Change it to return `TK_THEN` for `{` and `{` for `[`, etc.

Comment: @lhf Actually I don't think the lexer needs to be changed at all (`{` and `}` are already tokens). It probably makes sense to remove the `do`, `then` and `end` keywords, but that isn't strictly necessary. What is necessary is to change the parser to expect `{` and `}` in place of `do`/`then` and `end` respectively. But as I understand it, OP wants to know how to write a new interpreter, not change the existing one (I think).

Comment: I could not find TK_THEN or TK_END in that file. Also can I use http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/ to convert above modified BNF to c?

Comment: @sepp2k, it's much easier to change the lexer to recognize different tokens than to change the parser to accept different tokens.

Comment: @lhs But the lexer already recognizes those tokens, so there's nothing to change (except removing `then`, `do` and `end` if desired). And the parser *needs* to be changed because the tokens can now appear in different places than before. And that change isn't really all that complicated - just replace `TK_THEN` and `TK_DO` with `'{'` and `TK_END` with `}`.

Comment: You could all your comments in answers since they are very insightful. Also, answers are much more likely to be read by users than comments.

Comment: @mso Does that answer your question though? Because your previous comment made it sound like you wanted to create your own interpreter (or at least know how to) rather than forking the existing one.

Comment: I want to go via modifying BNF (rather than modifying C files as https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lparser.c.html). I think I can use BNFC ( http://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com ) to convert BNF to C? Will that C file on compilation produce an interpreter?

Comment: No, it will produce a parser (and a lexer). If you look at the source of the lua interpreter, bnfc will take care of the contents of `llex.c` and some of the contents of `lparser.c` (only some because it directly generates bytecode, not an AST). You'll have to do the rest (generating bytecode from the AST, executing the bytecode, implementing a GC, implementing the built-in functions) yourself.

Comment: How are these related to tokenizer, parser,  traverser,  transformer, codeGenerator and compiler as in https://github.com/thejameskyle/the-super-tiny-compiler/blob/master/the-super-tiny-compiler.js

Comment: @sepp2k, you're mixing concrete and abstract tokens.

Comment: @lhf No, I'm not. The lua lexer and parser use char literals to refer to single-character tokens and enum constants to refer to multi-char constants. So the keyword do is referred to as `TK_DO`, but `{` is simply referred to as `'{'`. Just look at the places where `'{'` is already used in lparser.c (namely the syntax for table constructors).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `then` with `{` and `end` with `}` conflicts with table constructors:

```
if a then print(1) end
```

becomes

```
if a { print(1) }
```

Conversely,

```
a = {}
```

becomes

```
a = then end
```

Comment: Can I assign `[ ]` as table constructor instead of `{ }`. The array index may be changed to a dot `.` Alternatively, Can I assign `[ ]` to replace `do` and `end`? But my main question is that what are further steps to create an interpreter?

Comment: I don't see the ambiguity here. Table constructors are expressions and, as far as I can tell, there are no places in the syntax where both `then ... end` or an expression would be allowed. I think the suggested syntax is unambiguous.

Comment: I want blocks to be delimited by `{ }` or `[ ]` or even `( )` not `do/then` and `end`.